# Ubuntu 14.04 and openjdk-r/openjdk-8

Tags: ubuntu, java

I am using `Ubuntu LTS 14.04` with `open-jdk 8u111-b14-3~14.04.1` from `openjdk-r PPA`.

The version was changed to `8u141-b15-3~14.04` and after installation on new machine I have problem with missing cacert file.

Related bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1706442 was marker as Invalid. Is there any chance that it will be fixed? Or is there any option to return previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to bite the bullet and upgrade to a version of Ubuntu (or some other distrbiution) that supports OpenJDK 8 as a first class package.

The bug you linked to will most likely not be fixed. That bug says "it's a bug in ca-certificate-java". It isn't. It is a bug in the openjdk package since the OpenJDK 8 package claims that it will break `ca-certificate-java`.

Can you contact the maintainers of that PPA and ask them to fix their builds for 14.04 instead? As I understand it, they have a number of options to fix things. A fix with a small amount of effort to support 14.04 would be to not depend on ca-certificates-java. OpenJDK builds can bundle certificates; bad as it is, it might be the only way to support something as old as 14.04. It is probably less bad than providing broken packages for 14.04.